# Android notification in background continue previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

```
sendNotification('Hello', 0, 1);

private void sendNotification(String message, int id, int notification_num) {

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    intent.setData(new Uri.Builder().scheme("data").build());
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("noti_number", notification_num);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Main.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("App Title")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setNumber(notification_num);
    nm.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

When application is opened intent.putExtra works fine, but when I close app (kill proccess), notification is coming but not with it extra than with new intent extra.

Problem is also with multiple notification, when app is closed, there are no grouping like I want it to be.
notificationBuilder.setNumber is always 0 in background.

Need help how to run app always in background or how to continue previous intent.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using GcmIntentService & GcmBroadcastReceiver, for more info click [on this link](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/).